# The cron job defines by the user not running

Tags: cron

How to run a command defined by a user `user1` on a crontab in ubuntu server?
There is no root access in the server but the user `user1` have all the root permissions. A cron tab needs to run every weekdays on 9:30 AM.
The command is

```
30 9 * * 1-5 python pythonfile.py
```

this cron tab is not running, only runs the cron jobs defined by root user.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your logs/email?
2. do `man 5 crontab`; looks like you have 6 values before your command, while `crond` only needs 5 followed by command to execute:

   The time and date fields are:

   ```
     field          allowed values
     -----          --------------
     minute         0-59
     hour           0-23
     day of month   1-31
     month          1-12 (or names, see below)
     day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
   ```
3. try:

> 30 9 * * 1-5 python pythonfile.py

Comment: the command is correct in the server. add one more * in the question only.